# Can you put All-Clad LTD2 in the oven?

Tags: equipment, oven

Just got an All-Clad LTD2 saute pan and I was wandering if it is save to put it in the oven. Thanks

Comment: Does your pan have a non-stick coating?

Comment: nope, looks like stainless on the inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:  sorry, this line is layered steel and anodized aluminum construction.

From the Amazon product description (almost certainly direct from the manufacturer), emphasis added:

> LTD2 is safe on all stovetops - except induction and backed by a
>   lifetime warranty. The “workhorse” of all cookware shapes, All-Clad
>   fry pans' versatile shape and size make them a frequent choice for
>   scrambling eggs and bacon on Sunday morning, or preparing a quick
>   chicken sauté dinner on a weeknight. **Our conventional fry pans go in
>   the oven and under the broiler.**

That is one of the primary benefits of the good All-Clad stuff, or similar cookware from other brands.

The only pots you don't want to put in the oven are ones with phenolic (sp?) or other plasticized handles or knobs--although some of these are rated to 400F degrees.  I also would not put non-stick pots in an oven above about 450F, or under the broiler.

All steel and aluminum pots are great, partially **because** they are oven and broiler safe.

Before I switched to all-steel exterior all-clad, I used anodized aluminum (the old, original Calphalon).   It also went into the oven and under the broiler without issue.   My current all-steel all clad has been going in the oven and under the broiler for many year without an issue.